# Bundle js apps with webpack for a wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, webpack, browserify

I am developing a WordPress plugin and it's heavily depends on javascript on admin side. Because it's a plugin and works on admin panel I have to be careful to prevent any conflict with other plugin's js codes, because it's like a common place, each plugin can load js libraries.

I am planning to use wordpress's default js scripts ( like jQuery, underscore, jquery-ui, etc. ) as external and bundle rest of the dependencies ( react, redux, numeral.js, etc. ) with webpack.

May this approach cause a conflict with another plugin's js code?

Maybe, if;

- Another plugin author decided to use webpack like I used.
- Another plugin loads a js library that it already in my dependency list but it's very old version.

Can Webpack, browserify, or another tool or approach help me to prevent this conflict issues?

Comment: Webpack will completely shield your code from the global namespace, provided you don't add anything to builtin objects like `window` which you probably wouldn't have done anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you bundle via webpack, including the webpack runtime itself, is exposed globally. You could bundle your own jQuery (as an example, you're obviously using WordPress's) and use it safely alongside the existing one, and neither would have issues. You can even load multiple webpack builds without conflicts (they would be 'unaware' of each other). Webpack wraps all of its code in an immediately-invoked function, so everything is scoped local to that function. So unless you explicitly make something global, there is no risk of conflicts.

Comment: What about in the scenario where the theme and several plugins are using webpack to bundle things. Isn't there a certain amount of overhead that is shared between all of these plugins / theme that will add weight to the page load?

Comment: @corradomatt the overhead that webpack itself adds is negligible. The only shared resources used by plugins/themes would be shared js libraries. If this is an issue you can load them separately and configure webpack to treat them as 'external' dependencies. In this case it will not try to bundle them and will expect them to be defined at runtime.

Comment: What about if a js library is registered by a plugin but the theme or another plugin (which also uses webpack) wants to be able to use it / call it in it's javascript?  Could I reference the webpack bundle name as an external library in the theme and have it load that JS from the plugin that registered it?

Comment: @corradomatt You can't use anything included in a webpack bundle from outside the bundle, unless that bundle has been built in a way that specifically exposes JS for use by the surrounding page (this is done by setting the 'target' option in webpack config to 'library'). So in other words, the plugin's JS would have had to have been built with this in mind, to allow other JS to use it. If it wasn't, it would be inadvisable to try to use it anyway; you don't want to rely on code that was intended for internal use only.